# CSS WOW Animation.css libarary when used with transform css property results in a jump after positioning

Tags: html, css, animate.css

I am trying to center an element vertically. This is the code I use:

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

Eventually, the element gets centered properly but, as I am using animate.css library and I am using the class=`"wow fadeIn`, the element fades in to the top 50% of the page then after fading into that place, it jumps -50% of its size because of the `translate(0,-50%)` part.

How can I get rid of the additional jump??

Comment: The animation likely sets a value for `transform` itself - and thereby overwrites your `translate`. You could perhaps try and add it back in, by manipulating/overwriting the properties applied by those classes - but if you just used an additional element, that will probably be easier - outer container for your centering, inside child element that gets animated for the fade-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a container that had the `fadeInUp` class name and its position is relative. Then I remove the fadeInUp from the div inside and it worked.